# Does having a jpg for a desktop background decrease battery time to 'fully discharged'?

Tags: 18.04, display, battery, desktop-background

I thought I had read that having a desktop background as a jpg from the pictures folder made no difference to power consumption compared to running the standard Ubuntu background.

However a few short experiments with powertop *seem* to show an increased wattage being used with a picture background. I am running 18.04 on an Asus laptop.

**Edit:**

On second observations, I'm not sure now that it does increase power usage. The question remains though, should it?

**Edit 2:**

I think [this](https://superuser.com/questions/135445/is-there-considerable-energy-saving-using-a-black-background-on-my-website), is what I remember reading. On the face of it, the background appears to make no difference to power usage.

Comment: Use `powertop` to see what is using power. I find the conclusion doubtful...

Comment: I think the suggestion in the link you provided would be effective with OLED screens.

Answer (score -1):

It needs more power for the illumination system of your screen (especially laptop screen) when you have a bright image shown or you have a bright software running. So, for power saving reasons, use a dark background image or change to a dark software design (if possible..).
Style and complexity of an image has no impact and of course same is it on mobile phones.

Comment: *Especially on laptop screen** which is usually LCD with backlight this is not the case. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/115647/does-it-save-battery-to-have-your-desktop-background-set-on-a-dark-color) or [here more detailed](https://www.quora.com/Does-a-white-background-use-more-energy-on-an-LCD-than-if-it-was-set-to-black).

Comment: @Rovo - I think that was the article that I originally read. As I have an LCD screen, it appears the background makes no difference